# DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL doesn't return the complete procedure. Its truncated

Tags: oracle11g

```
SET echo off;
set pagesize 0;
SET long 500000;
spool GenerateProcedure_Creation.sql
begin
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', false);
end;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL(u.object_type,u.object_name,u.owner) DDL
     from dba_objects u where u.OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE' and owner in ('ADMIN');
spool off;
```

I have used the above code. But getting some procedures as truncated.

Answer (score 2):

similar to above but adjusting to be within max lengths

```
set trimspool off
set linesize 32000
set long 20000000
set pagesize 0 
column ddl format a50000
```

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('*[INDEX|TABLE]*','*TABLENAME*','*OWNER*') as ddl from dual

Answer (score 1):

You can play around with the set parameters:

```
set trimspool off
set linesize 100000
set LONG 20000000
set PAGESIZE 0
```

and eventually force the type of your DDL column

```
column DDL format a50000 --set your own size here
```